# Hadoop distribution

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop2

I was using IBM big insights via VNC software (remote access) provided by the university I study but I can't access Internet through that desktop. To use some data samples available in internet, I decided to install **Hadoop** in my laptop (single cluster), but I found that there are many distributions, So What's the best free **Hadoop** distribution for training as a beginner ?

```
1) Amazon Elastic MapReduce
2) Cloudera CDH Hadoop Distribution
3) Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP)
4) MapR Hadoop Distribution
5) IBM Open Platform
6) Microsoft Azure's HDInsight -Cloud based Hadoop Distrbution
7) Pivotal Big Data Suite
8) Datameer Professional
9) Datastax Enterprise Analytics
10) Dell- Cloudera Apache Hadoop Solution.
```

Answer (score 0):

CDH and Hortonworks are the easiest to get a single node cluster up and running, and are also very widely used so you can find a lot of troubleshooting resources.

If you just want to write application code/run arbitrary MapReduce jobs rather than learn the Hadoop systems architecture, then Amazon EMR is more suitable.